# MailGun UNAUTHORIZED error 401 after deploying to HEROKU

Tags: laravel, heroku, lumen, guzzle, mailgun

My lumen PHP app works fine in localhost, using mailgun to send emails. However, after deploying to heroku, when I try to send email, error 401 unauthorized shows up.

PHP, lumen backend, GuzzleHttp installed.

Error Message

```
"message": "Client error: `POST https://api.mailgun.net/v3/sandbox-my-domain-name.mailgun.org/messages.mime` resulted in a `401 UNAUTHORIZED` response:\nForbidden\n",
    "exception": "GuzzleHttp\\Exception\\ClientException",
    "file": "/app/vendor/guzzlehttp/guzzle/src/Exception/RequestException.php",
    "line": 111,
    "trace": [
        {
            "file": "/app/vendor/guzzlehttp/guzzle/src/Middleware.php",
            "line": 66,
            "function": "create",
            "class": "GuzzleHttp\\Exception\\RequestException",
            "type": "::"
        },
        {
            "file": "/app/vendor/guzzlehttp/promises/src/Promise.php",
            "line": 203,
            "function": "GuzzleHttp\\{closure}",
            "class": "GuzzleHttp\\Middleware",
            "type": "::"
        },
        {
            "file": "/app/vendor/guzzlehttp/promises/src/Promise.php",
            "line": 156,
            "function": "callHandler",
            "class": "GuzzleHttp\\Promise\\Promise",
            "type": "::"
        },
        ...this error message is very long so I'll only paste it until here
```

My env file set up, same in my computer as on heroku config settings

```
MAIL_MAILER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=smtp.mailgun.org
MAIL_PORT=587
MAIL_USERNAME=postmaster@andbox-my-domain-name.mailgun.org
MAIL_PASSWORD=my-password
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=tls
MAIL_FROM_ADDRESS=postmaster@sandbox-my-domain-name.mailgun.org
MAIL_FROM_NAME="My app"
MAILGUN_DOMAIN=sandbox-my-domain-name.mailgun.org
MAILGUN_SECRET=my-api-secret
```

I have tested many times, mailgun works completely fine in localhost using the env config I listed above. Now after deploying to heroku, it doesn't work anymore, does anyone have similar experience?

Below article talks about if vendor folder isn't present, mailgun won't work.
https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/laravel/mailgun-gives-401-unathorized-response

I have ran composer install on heroku console, still, mailgun keeps returning error 401.

```
heroku run composer install
```

Really lost here, looked at various articles and questions on stackoverflow, can't seem to find anything useful at the moment. Any help is appreciated, thank you.

Comment: Update, I found out where I was doing wrong. For env configuration, MAIL_MAILER (or MAIL_DRIVER) has to be smtp, on my heroku setup I put down mailgun for MAIL_MAILER, which didn't work. After editing back to smtp, everything worked perfectly.